# Angular 6 - Multiple functions in one directive. Function onResize() onInit()

Tags: angular, function, resize, angular6, angular2-directives

I am trying to change some of my elements when window is being resized or when it is set to some resolution when I refresh the page. So...

```
export class ResizeDirective {

constructor(
    public renderer: Renderer2, public el: ElementRef,
) {
}

const element = document.getElementsByClassName('myElement'); // Can I have something like that? I get some error

@HostListener('window:resize') onResize() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 920)
       this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'resized');
       this.renderer.addClass(element, 'alsoResized');
} else {
       this.renderer.removeClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'resized');
       this.renderer.removeClass(element, 'alsoResized');
}


onInit() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 920)
       this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'resized');
       this.renderer.addClass(element, 'alsoResized');
    } else {
       this.renderer.removeClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'resized');
       this.renderer.removeClass(element, 'alsoResized');
    }
}

}
```

How to bind it to html?

If I have just one function doing sth, I simply

```
<div class="myClass" appResize></div>
```

How to deal with two? I've tried:

```
<div class="myClass" [appResize]="onResize" [appResize]="onInit"></div>
```

---

**My idea**

```
export class ResizeDirective implements OnInit {

constructor(
    public renderer: Renderer2, public el: ElementRef,
) {

}

public element = document.getElementsByClassName('myElement');

ngOnInit() {
    this.addColor();
}

@HostListener('window:resize')
onResize(){
    this.addColor();
}

public addColor() {

if (window.innerWidth < 920)
   this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'resized');
   this.renderer.addClass(element, 'alsoResized');
      } else {
   this.renderer.removeClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'resized');
   this.renderer.removeClass(element, 'alsoResized');
    }


 }
```

This way I write one function and just call it when I need - on load and when screen is resized! In html I just need to add the whole directive name, like so:
       `<div class="myClass" appResize></div>`
**Pretty simple!**

Comment: Not the answer, but I suggest you use flex to make your app responsive: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/API-Documentation

Comment: what do you want to bind with html?

Comment: @PeterKim, I'm afraid working with this plug and bootstrap which has it's own version of flex may not work together. Also I find my solution perfectly simple enough. The whole mediaqueries are made by bootstrap, I just want to adjust couple of things, so I don't need the whole thing you've suggested, but thanks! I'll keep that in mind ;)

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal, I wanted to bind directive to element which makes it possible to call, I think there is no other way. <div class="myClass" **appResize**></div>